# Given the indexes corresponding to each row, get the corresponding elements from a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given indexes for each row, how to return the corresponding elements in a 2-d matrix?
For instance, In array of `np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]])` I expect to see the output `[[1,2],[4,5]]` given `indxs = np.array([[0,1],[0,1]])`. Below is what I've tried:

```
a= np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]])
indxs = np.array([[0,1],[0,1]]) #means return the elements located at 0 and 1 for each row
#I tried this, but it returns an array with shape (2, 2, 4) 
a[idxs]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting two times your array is that when you do `a[[0,1]]` you are selecting the rows 0 and 1 from your array a, which are indeed your entire array.

```
In[]: a[[0,1]]

Out[]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

You can get the desired output using slides. That would be the easiest way.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]])
a[:,0:2]

Out []: array([[1, 2],
               [4, 5]])
```

In case you are still interested on indexing, you could also get your output doing:

```
In[]: [list(a[[0],[0,1]]),list(a[[1],[0,1]])]

Out[]: [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

The [NumPy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html) documentation gives you a really nice overview on how indexes work.

Comment: This section on integer array indexing is better. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing

Answer (score 0):

```
In [120]: indxs = np.array([[0,1],[0,1]])
In [121]: a= np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]])
     ...: indxs = np.array([[0,1],[0,1]]) #
```

You need to provide an index for the first dimension, one that broadcasts with with `indxs`.

```
In [122]: a[np.arange(2)[:,None], indxs]
Out[122]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

`indxs` is (2,n), so you need a (2,1) array to give a (2,n) result